# How to select span elements of specific container (<div> defined by CSS class) using Xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

i have the following HTML stucture  :

```
  <div class="divone"><span class="my_sapn">Sports</span></div>
  <div class="divtwo"><span class="my_sapn">Arts</span></div>
  <div class="divtwo"><span class="my_sapn">Computer</span></div>
  <div class="divone"><span class="my_sapn">Fashion</span></div>
  <div class="divtwo"><span class="my_sapn">Familly</span></div>
```

What i want to achive is get all elements that have the class `my_span` inside the divs that have the class `divone` only. 
my code get all span with the class my_span, output : `Sports, Arts , Computer , Fashion , Familly`

 the desired output : `Sports , Fashion`

Mycode :

```
List<WebElement> MainCategory = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class=\"my_span\"]"));
```

**PS :** i must use `By.xpath` not `By.classame`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this result is using the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
List<WebElement> MainCategory = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='divone' and span/@class='my_span']/span"));
```

Another way to achieve the same output is

```
List<WebElement> MainCategory = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[../@class='divone' and @class='my_span']"));
```

The output in both cases is the same:

> Sports
> Fashion